# I want to send a message by email but the Intent doesn't work. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is a part of my app where I send an email using a button but for some reason the Intent doesn't work and I don't understand why.

```
binding.IvMail.setOnClickListener {
    val email = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        .setType("text/plain")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.email_subject))
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.email_text))

    if (activity?.packageManager?.resolveActivity(email, 0) != null) {
        startActivity(email)
    }

}
```

I already searched for other ways to do it but everyone is using Intent.

Comment: Your code seems fine. I tried at my end and it's opening email app with expected subject and body. Can you please explain more what is happening at your end? You may also like to check if you onClickListener is set properly on correct UI element.

Answer (score 1):

```
         // try this(JAVA).
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    ////For(Kotlin)
        sendEmail(recipient, subject, message)

 private fun sendEmail(recipient: String, subject: String, message: 
String) {
        /*ACTION_SEND action to launch an email client installed on your Android device.*/
        val mIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        /*To send an email you need to specify mailto: as URI using 
setData() method
        and data type will be to text/plain using setType() method*/
        mIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
        mIntent.type = "text/plain"
        // put recipient email in intent
        /* recipient is put as array because you may wanna send email to multiple emails
           so enter comma(,) separated emails, it will be stored array*/
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf(recipient))
        //put the Subject in the intent
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
        //put the message in the intent
        mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)


        try {
            //start email intent
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Choose Email Client..."))
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            //if any thing goes wrong for example no email client application or any exception
            //get and show exception message
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `ACTION_SEND`.

See your new code below:

```
binding.IvMail.setOnClickListener {
    val email = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO) // here you have to use SENDTO
        .setType("text/plain")
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.email_subject))
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.email_text))

    if (activity?.packageManager?.resolveActivity(email, 0) != null) {
        startActivity(email)
    }

}
```

Let me know if not solved yet

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. If it is not running, it would seem that your if statement is not satisfied and is skipping Intent resolvement.

What you can do to determine the problem is:

1. Debug if the code blocks are reached, by setting breakpoints and running debug app like this:

[image: Run debug app]

[image: Debug breakpoints]

2. Log if the code blocks above are reached, by setting logs and looking for them in logcat tool like this:

[image: Logs]

[image: Logcat]

3. You could also look in the Logcat for errors that happened when the intent was being ran.